# How to use MySQL in OSGi application with Maven?

Tags: java, maven, osgi, mysql-connector, apache-felix

How do I use MySQL in an OSGi application with Maven and using Apache Felix?

I added this to my `pom.xml` file:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.13</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And this to the Activator (for testing purposes):

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname", "user", "");
```

But when I run the application via Apache Felix, I get this error while loading the bundle:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname
```

What is the problem and how can I solve it?

---

**EDIT**:

Although I read somewhere that since some version of Java the driver does not have to be explicitly registered (I use Java 11), I tried to add this code right before the `.getConnection()` call:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

However, this only generates a different error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver not found
```

Comment: can you show the line that creates the instance of the Driver?

Comment: @benji2505 I have updated the question.

Comment: The solution beIow make sense to me since it is Felix specific. If you still have issues I think the argument of the Driver instantiation might be off. Try this:
Driver driver = (Driver) Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this row instead of loading the driver via `Class.forName()`:

```
new com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the driver into memory first before using getConnection(...) method. Use the following to load the class:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
```

This automatically registers the mysql driver with DriverManager.
Then you can use:

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname", "user", "");
```

to get a connection instance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, this does not seem to solve the problem (see my edited question).

Answer (score 0):

You need to

1. First download the MySQL connector OSGI jar ,this pom dependency
   wont work.MySQL Osgi jar will have exported packages in manifest file.
2. Then install it as a bundle in Apache Felix system console.
3. Then configure the connection in system/console/configMgr under data
           sources

Then use below code to read the configured data source.

```
String filter = "(&(objectclass=javax.sql.DataSource)(datasource.name="+configurationId+"))";
                    ServiceReference[] refs = bundleContext.getAllServiceReferences(null, filter);
                    if(refs != null && refs.length == 1) {
                        dataSource = (javax.sql.DataSource) bundleContext.getService(refs[0]);
                    }
```

where bundleContext will be your osgi context (org.osgi.framework.BundleContext)